# open "sapisvr.exe" file in C#

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I need to open this sapisvr.exe file on button click using C#, i tried using process.start("file name") but couldn't get success.

File path:
**%windir%\Speech\Common\sapisvr.exe -SpeechUX**
   or
**C:\Windows\Speech\Common\sapisvr.exe**

However when i opened it in command prompt (using this path:%windir%\Speech\Common\sapisvr.exe -SpeechUX) the it successfully got opened.

Can someone tell me how to open said exe file in c# code?

Thanks,
Vinod Bhatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, check whether you have the .exe available at the supplied location. If so, follow the given logic. I have the sapisvr.exe at the following location and it's starts as expected.

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\Speech\Common\sapisvr.exe", @"-SpeechUX");
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me as well. :) One more thing that i need to know. Can we make it more path independent, i mean if some one has installed it at "E\:....." or other directory then how it will work?

Comment: @VinodBhatt, Yes. You can have your installation directory in app.config file and read it from configuration when call Process.Start.